# chkdsk multiple drives on startup

Tags: batch-file, fsutil

I wish to schedule multiple chkdsk on startup:

"fsutil dirty set [drive]:" marks the drive as dirty and should be scanned but for some reason it scans C and skips D.

Is there any way to force the scan?

Comment: This is a "question and answer" site. As this is not a question, it will be closed and probably deleted soon. Please rewrite it as an question. Nobody hinders you to answer your own question - in an answer.

Comment: Right you are, i'll rephrase the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it happens, yes there is.

"chkntfs /c [drive]:" ovverides startup behavior to make sure the drive is scanned on startup if the dirty bit is set.

so the final code will be something like:

```
fsutil dirty set c: 
fsutil dirty set d: 
chkntfs /c c: d:
```